# Post on Twitter using C# Desktop Window Form Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, twitter

I am using Single-user OAuth
i have generated all
**ConsumerKey**

**ConsumerSecret**

**AccessToken**

**AccessTokenSecret**  from my twitter application

Read and Write permission is enabled

using callback and website=  http ://127.0.0.1:3000

I am using two Methods to Post status on Twitter

First Method use a Request to post on twitter ,It gives 401 unauthorize error

```
  public void MethodOne()
    {
        string status = "@screenname Godddod day";
        string postBody = "status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(status);
        string oauth_consumer_key = ConsumerKey;
        string oauth_consumerSecret = ConsumerSecret;
        string oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
        string oauth_version = "1.0";
        string oauth_token = AccessToken;
        string oauth_token_secret = AccessTokenSecret;
        string oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        string oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        SortedDictionary<string, string> basestringParameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
        //include the "in_reply_to_status_id" parameter if you need to reply to particular tweet.
        basestringParameters.Add("in_reply_to_status_id",
          "status id of the post to which we are going to reply");
        basestringParameters.Add("status", Uri.EscapeDataString(status));
        basestringParameters.Add("oauth_version", oauth_version);
        basestringParameters.Add("oauth_consumer_key", oauth_consumer_key);
        basestringParameters.Add("oauth_nonce", oauth_nonce);
        basestringParameters.Add("oauth_signature_method", oauth_signature_method);
        basestringParameters.Add("oauth_timestamp", oauth_timestamp);
        basestringParameters.Add("oauth_token", oauth_token);

        //Build the signature string
        string baseString = String.Empty;
        baseString += "POST" + "&";
        baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json") + "&";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in basestringParameters)
        {
            baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(entry.Key + "=" + entry.Value + "&");
        }

        //GS - Remove the trailing ambersand char, remember 
        //it's been urlEncoded so you have to remove the 
        //last 3 chars - %26
        baseString = baseString.Substring(0, baseString.Length - 3);

        //Build the signing key    
        string signingKey = Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumerSecret) +
          "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret);

        //Sign the request
        HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signingKey));
        string signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(baseString)));

        //Tell Twitter we don't do the 100 continue thing
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
          @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?in_reply_to_status_id=status id");

        string authorizationHeaderParams = String.Empty;
        authorizationHeaderParams += "OAuth ";
        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_nonce=" + "\"" +
          Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce) + "\",";
        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_signature_method=" +
          "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method) + "\",";
        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_timestamp=" + "\"" +
          Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp) + "\",";
        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_consumer_key=" + "\"" +
          Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key) + "\",";
        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_token=" + "\"" +
          Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token) + "\",";
        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_signature=" + "\"" +
          Uri.EscapeDataString(signatureString) + "\",";
        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_version=" + "\"" +
          Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version) + "\"";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeaderParams);
        webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        byte[] bodyBytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(postBody);
        stream.Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();

        //Allow us a reasonable timeout in case Twitter's busy
        webRequest.Timeout = 3 * 60 * 1000;
        try
        {
   //         webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("enter proxy details/address");
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Second Method uses twitterizer 2.4.2, It gives System.Exception

```
   public void Method2()
     {
    OAuthTokens TOKEN = new OAuthTokens();
    TOKEN.AccessToken = AccessToken;
    TOKEN.AccessTokenSecret = AccessTokenSecret;
    TOKEN.ConsumerKey = ConsumerKey;
    TOKEN.ConsumerSecret = ConsumerSecret;

    TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(
                TOKEN,
                "Testing!! It works (hopefully).");

    if (response.Result == RequestResult.Success)
    {
        throw new Exception("doNE");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(response.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```